# How can I measure pytest codecoverage?

Tags: c, pytest

I have an API which is written in C and i have some python tests (pytest). I don't know how to measure this tests code coverage of my API.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question and give some more details?

Comment: 1. naturally, `pytest` has plugins only for the python code coverage. 2. there is no common tool or library for C code coverage like what `coverage` is for python. There is `gcov`, but it works only for code compiled with GCC, so no windows/MSVC which has own coverage support in Visual Studio AFAIK. ICC also has own coverage tool builtin. Depending on what your particular setup is, write your own wrapper in python and invoke it from `pytest` hooks or fixtures in order to record and post-process code coverage.

Comment: I want measure how my pytest tests cover API